# Estructura IF-ELSE en Excel

Tags: excel

Estimada comunidad tengo la siguiente tabla en excel:

[image: tabla ejemplo]

Estoy intentando cumplir la siguiente sentencia:

Si la casilla de NUEVA EXISTENCIA está vacía, el valor de DIFERENCIA es el resultado de restar el TOTAL menos SISTEMA

de lo contrario;

si la casilla de NUEVA EXISTENCIA tiene un valor X, el valor de TOTAL es el valor de RECUENTO y el valor de DIFERENCIA es el resultado de restar el TOTAL menos NUEVA EXISTENCIA.

Agradeceria que me pudieran ayudar con esto, saludos.

Comment: Prueba a consultar el apartado `4` de [este link](https://www.pcworld.com/article/423075/excel-logical-formulas-5-simple-if-statements-to-get-started.html "este link"). Te explica como hacer nested if's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se puede solucionar con dos fórmulas.

1. En la columna **TOTAL** necesitas evaluar si **NUEVA EXISTENCIA** está vacía para dejarla en cero (o vacía si prefieres), y si tiene un valor, le asignas el mismo valor de **RECUENTO**... Así: **=IF(D2="";0;H2)**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2. En la columna **DIFERENCIA** necesitas un `if` anidado, en el que evalúas si **TOTAL** es igual a cero (o vacío). Si se cumple la condición, entra en juego el `if` anidado, así: Si **NUEVA EXISTENCIA** está vacío, restas **TOTAL** menos **SISTEMA**. Si no se cumple la primera condición, restas **TOTAL** menos **NUEVA EXISTENCIA**. Así la fórmula quedaría de las siguiente manera: **=IF(I2=0;IF(D2="";I2-C2);I2-D2)**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedes observar en mi ejemplo, las condiciones funcionan. Sólo debes adaptar las referencias a las celdas en tu archivo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

La formula deberia ser de la siguiente manera 
`=SI(D2="",N2-C2,M2-D2)`

Ten en cuenta que la formula anterior no actualiza la celda total sino  que resta directamente desde la celda recuento.
Puedes actualizar la columna total usando otra formula similar a la anterior en esta columna.